# bug z-index ViewPager with PageTransformer doesn't work with getChildDrawingOrder

Tags: java, android

I'm looking for a solution since too long now and I feel stuck. So I decided to write my first post on stackoverflow :)

I'm trying to do a CoverFlow for my app in android 4.0 and higher, after some research I decided to do that with a `ViewPager`, to increase the `OffscreenPageLimit`, and to put a negative margin and in bonus a little `PageTransformer` for the effect.

So my bug is about the z-index when the margin is too negative one image overlay an other, because of the drawing order, the image on the left is on the top and it's not pretty at all.

See bug here --> http://img33.imageshack.us/img33/2448/r1l1.jpg

So after some research the solution appear to be to overwrite the `getChildDrawingOrder` method in my `ViewPager` class. I did it like that :

```
private void setChildDrawingOrder() {
    int count = getChildCount();
    positions = new SparseIntArray(count);
    for (int i=0, j=0 ; i<count ; i++) {
        if (i == position) {
            positions.put(count-1, i);
        } else {
            j++;
            positions.put(count-1-j, i);
        }
    }
    mNeedsToSetChildDrawingOrder = false;
}

@Override
protected int getChildDrawingOrder(int childCount, int i) {
    if(i == 0 && mNeedsToSetChildDrawingOrder) setChildDrawingOrder();

    return positions.get(i);
}
```

Where positions is an `SparseIntArray`, where the item on the top got the higher value (childCount-1). I fill it in the `onPageSelected` (method implement with `OnPageChangeListener` on my `ViewPager`) to get the position of the item that i want it to be on the top.

```
@Override
public void onPageSelected(int position) {
    if (lastPosition != position) {
        lastPosition = position;
        ViewPager viewPager = ((MainActivity)mAdapterContext).getViewPager();
        viewPager.setPosition(position);
    }
}
```

I can't see where is my mistake! I also tried something with `bringChildToFront` in the `onPageSelected` without any success, probably because the `PageTransformer` redraw everything after the `onPageSelected` is called.

Any idea ?

Thanks

EDIT 15/10/13 : 
I edit my code because I didn't catch what the method do very weel! It's "to get the index of the child to draw for that iteration." and not "when should I draw child i?" (thx to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14504649/getchilddrawingorder-called-used-erratically))

I also had some NullPointerException` because the count where not everytime the same so I move it into my ViewPager.

It's way better but still have some drawing bug! My positions `SparseIntArray` look good so I don't understand. It seems to appear kind of randomly...

Comment: [check this link may be help you](http://androidcustomviews.com/portfolio/viewpagerindicator-android/)

Comment: @GirishBhutiya really interesting code! but I didn't find something about the z-index, I think it's more about `PageIndicator`

Comment: Too bad, noone has an answer for this - I got almost the same problem. You can modify the z-value of an view directly by View.setZ(float), but this requires API level 21. There has to be a solution without raising the requirements to API 21 ...