# Replace last child with first child in FrameLayout

Tags: android

If I have a FrameLayout with a couple of children Views and would like to replace their order inside FrameLayout. What would be the most efficient way to do that?

```
<FrameLayout>
  <View1/>
  <View2/>
  <View3/>
</FrameLayout>
```

So, in this case I would like to remove View3 and move to a location of View1. After replacement, FrameLayout should look like this:

```
<FrameLayout>
  <View3/>
  <View1/>
  <View2/>
</FrameLayout>
```

I can try with a lot of addView() and removeView() methods but that doesn't look to efficient to me.

Comment: Now are you doing this because you want to change the depth order in which the views appear on screen or do you want to change the index of the view?

Comment: @idunnololz, I want to change the depth. So, View3 should be visible behind View1 and View2 after change.

Comment: related, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14504649/getchilddrawingorder-called-used-erratically/41746374#41746374

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If xml will has ids,

```
<FrameLayout>
  <View1  android:id="@+id/view1" />
  <View2  android:id="@+id/view2" />
  <View3  android:id="@+id/view3" />
</FrameLayout>
```

in your code you can call `bringToFront` on your java object that is the view you want to "bringToFront" :

```
findViewById(R.id.view1).bringToFront();
```

Of locate the view by other means (iteration, param from onClickListener) and call `bringToFront()`

Comment: Thank you. I guess in my case I would need to call bringToFront() two times. First time on view1 and then on view2 as I need them to be in order view3-view1-view2.

Comment: yep,  you got this now. :)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you are after there are two ways of doing this.

If you want one view to display **above** another view, you simply need to call `View.bringToFront()`.

If you actually want to change the index of the view, you only need one `addView()` and one `removeView()` call. For instance, in your example, you would just need to do

```
View v = frameLayout.getChildAt(2);
frameLayout.removeViewAt(2);
frameLayout.addView(v, 0);
```

Comment: [bringtofront does a re-order](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/view/ViewGroup.java#1313)